# Binding formview with profile in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2005, profile-provider

I want to display and update user profile using FormView control. But I dont know exactly how to do this.

I am using custom providers for Roles, Membership and Profile. Everything is working fine.

Can anybody provide solution?

Thanks for sharing your valuable time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sections in the following link would give you a overview of this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyf1dk77(VS.85).aspx